# Recommended way to concatenate multiple columns and separate with delimiter?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
ROW_ID, ID_A, ID_B, ID_C, ID_D
1001, A, NULL, NULL, NULL
1002, A, NULL, B, NULL
1003, NULL, B, NULL, NULL
1004, NULL, NULL, C, D
```

I'd like to get it in the form:

```
ROW_ID, ID_COMBINED
1001, "A"
1002, "A, B"
1003, "B"
1004, "C, D"
```

At first I set up the query so the initial table values were empty strings instead of blanks, then just using a `CONCATENATE(A,', ', B,', ',C,', ',D)` approach, but that would give me values like:

```
ROW_ID, ID_COMBINED
1001, "A,,"
1002, "A,B,,"
1003, ",B,,"
1004, ",,C,D"
```

I also tried some combinations of `NULLIF()` but when I coalesce columns with NULL values, I lose the combined string aspect with an override like:

```
ROW_ID, ID_COMBINED
1001, "A"
1002, "B"
1003, "B"
1004, "D"
```

Is there a better way to concatenate the data here so the end results are delimited strings? Should I just do the concatenate with the floating commas then remove those at the very end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the function [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
SELECT ROW_ID,
       CONCAT_WS(',', ID_A, ID_B, ID_C, ID_D) ID_COMBINED
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d697831322bdb725a930830c152a7d24).
Results:

| ROW_ID | ID_COMBINED |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | A |
| 1002 | A,B |
| 1003 | B |
| 1004 | C,D |